# Difference between _.forEach and _.forOwn in lodash

Tags: foreach, lodash

What is the difference between these two methods when iterating over an object?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The difference lies in that if the collection over which you are iterating is an object which  has a `length` property, then the `_.forEach()` will iterate over it as if it were an array, whereas the `_.forOwn()` will iterate over it like an object.

Assume you have the object:

```js
a = {
  x: 100, 
  y: 200, 
  length: 2
}
```

If you iterate over it as:

```js
_.forEach(a, function(val, key) {
  console.log('a[' + key + '] = ' + val); 
});
```

you'll get output:

```js
a[0] = undefined
a[1] = undefined
```

whereas iterating over it with `_.forOwn()` you'll get the more reasonable:

```js
a[x] = 100
a[y] = 200
a[length] = 2
```

Comment: This is a poor example because I have used _.forEach and _.each to iterate over objects hundreds of times in code I have written. Even the lodash official docs show examples of each and forEach iterating over object. The reason you are getting undefined is because your object has a key value pair where the the key is "length" and if you create a normal object without "length" it will iterate

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs for forOwn the iterator *must* be an object.
With _.each and .forEach you can use this on array or an object.